# Not able to call Cordova Custom Plugin in Angular2 App

Tags: cordova, angular, jquery-mobile, typescript, plugins

I am developing an app using Angular2 and want to create a custom plugin . But I am not able to call it from the App. I followed the entire steps to add cordova in angular app listed in the following tutorial:
https://www.becompany.ch/en/blog/tech/2016/10/19/creating-apache-cordova-app-with-angular2.html
 and was able to add in-built cordova plugins in the App. But in case of adding a custom plugin, .js files added in www of cordova folder gets deleted when tried to run using cli. Only index.html file created in angular is included in www folder of cordova. Kindly help to resolve the issue as we are unable to define any custom plugin in our App. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Dear All, please help to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: hi did you found an solution for this?